# Error in converting image in png

Tags: php, type-conversion

I am trying to convert the image from jpg into png.Its work fine

```
$src1 = "Camel.jpg";
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src1);
imagepng($image, "new.png");
```

But I put the "src1" instead of "new.png" the conversion is failed.

```
$src1 = "Camel.jpg";
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src1);
imagepng($image, $src1);
```

That means the conversion when I create the same image name as `.png` file

Comment: `$src1 = Camel.jpg` not `Camel.png`. that's why conversion failed. Do you want same name for image?

Comment: Yes I want same name for image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second code `$src1 ="Camel.jpg"` not `Camel.png`. that's why conversion failed.

Do you want the same name for the image? If yes do like below:-

```
$src = "camel.jpg"; 

$src1 = basename($src); 

$path_parts = pathinfo($src1);

$originalfilename = $path_parts['filename']; 

$ext = pathinfo($src1, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 

$imagesrori = imagecreatefromjpeg($src); 

imagepng($imagesrori, $originalfilename . ".png");
```

Comment: But how to get the filename.png after converting the image

Comment: `$originalfilename . ".png"`. that's it.

Comment: @Nandy  glad to help you :):)